# Accepting and then Declining Grad School Admissions Offer

Tags: graduate-admissions

I've applied to a 5 grad schools for Engineering Management and I'm yet to receive the decisions from 4 schools.

One of the schools has offered me admissions as well as a scholarship offer. However, I've the deadline to respond to this in about another week's time. This school is my 5th choice among the 5 schools. Can I accept the offer now and then later decline it if I get into any of the other schools?

Or should I ask for a date extension as to when I can accept or decline their offer?﻿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I accept the offer now and then later decline it if I get into any of the other schools? Or should I ask for a date extension as to when I can accept or decline their offer?

Asking for an extension is better, since that doesn't mislead (whereas accepting and then declining does).